# Occasional org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: person.name of com.example.Scholarship

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: person.name of com.example.Scholarship

My entity Scholarship has a field "person" (entity Person) which has a field "name" (String)
When I use Criteria to perform a simple select on the database I get this exception.

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: person.name of com.example.Scholarship

here is the method I use to perform the select:

```
    public <T> Collection<T> findAll(Class<T> classe, PagingInformation paging, String orderField, String orderType) throws DAOException {
    Long total = (Long) getSession().createQuery("select count(*) from " + classe.getName()).uniqueResult();

    if (paging != null) {
        paging.setTotalRegistros((int) total.longValue());
    }

    Criteria c = getCriteria(classe);
    c.setCacheable(true);
    if (paging != null) {
        c.setFirstResult(paging.getPaginaAtual() * paging.getTamanhoPagina());
        c.setMaxResults(paging.getTamanhoPagina());
    }
    if (orderType.equals("asc")) {
        c.addOrder(Order.asc(orderField));
    } else {
        c.addOrder(Order.desc(orderField));
    }
    return c.list();
}
```

I am passing to orderField the String "person.name" and the orderType "asc". The point is, Person has another field, id (long), when I pass "person.id" it works just fine. What is the matter then? I could not use use a field of a field in order to perform a sort using Criteria?

p.s.: the problem is not uppercase or this sort of misspelling, I got all the getters methods just right.

Comment: Can you post the generated query?

Comment: The exception is thrown before any query is generated

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `join` between `Scholarship` and `Person` and then use that join to order by the `name` field.